# Is it possible to assign masks in an Adobe Animate CC HTML5/Canvas project via Javascript?

Tags: flash, adobe, animate-cc

I've done some digging and can't find any clear documentation on this. When the user clicks the stage, I would like to pull an instance of Symbol A from the library and place it on the stage, then pull an instance of Symbol B and assign it as a mask.

I am sure Symbol B is a "valid" mask, as it simply contains a shape.

In the old days, this would be as simple as:

```
symbolAInstance.mask = symbolBInstance;
```

Any way to accomplish this using JS/CreateJS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MovieClips can not be used directly as masks in CreateJS, only Shapes/Graphics.
http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html#property_mask

If you want to use something more complex like a Bitmap or MovieClip, it is possible, but it takes a few steps, and has limitations.

1. Cache the MovieClip you want to use as a mask
2. Create an [AlphaMaskFilter](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/AlphaMaskFilter.html) on the "masked" clip pointing to the mask clip's `cacheCanvas` (the bitmap generated by the cache)
3. Cache the "masked" clip to apply the filter.

The documentation for the AlphaMaskFilters has a simple example. http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/AlphaMaskFilter.html

One of the main limitations is that if you change the mask or masked clips (play timeline, change size, etc), then you will have to re-cache whatever changes. So if the mask changes, both the mask and masked clip need to be re-cached. Doing this to animate a mask is *very* expensive, and should be avoided if possible.

Hope that helps.